# Two independent copies of React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, browserify

I am developing a site for a customer. It is composed by React components and I am bundling libs such as **react** and **react-dom** in  <strike>a standalone</strike> an external bundle, using browserify. The problem is that <strike>an external</strike> a 3rd party widget provider ships widgets with a script bundle, containing a different React version, also built with browserify.

Is there a way to avoid a collision without having the client remove React from his bundle script?

Comment: can the 3rd party not ship with react?

Comment: Can you post your code?

Comment: @DanielA.White The 3rd party has indicated that upgrading to react 0.14.7 is something that will take them a while, also I would like to keep it separate so that we can upgrade our React at a later stage, not having to take into account 3rd party providers.

Answer (score 0):

It shouldn't be a problem to build bundle with react not poluting global scope. There is even option for this in browserify: `--standalone`.

Comment: React hasn't polluted the global scope. The problem is that `require('react')` on the client may or may not return the 3rd party bundled react. It is more that the the two bundle's _require_ are colliding.

Comment: Standalone bundle has (or should have) it's own `require` copy, that points to your version of rect